# Digits of a smaller integer present in a larger integer

Tags: arithmetic, integers

Given, for example,

*N* = 31,41**5**,**92**6,535

*n* = **592**

and notice that *n* is a decimal digit substring of *N*.

Can we confirm the presence *n*'s digits in *N* by arithmetic?

---

**Some context**: The problem is testing a function that returns the bits from *i* to *j* of a 32-bit object. It does so by bit manipulation. Using automated arithmetic to check that the returned segment of bits is correct makes it feasible to test all 32-bit integers and all *i*,*j* combinations. The base (decimal vs. binary) is irrelevant in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the $2$ is in the ten thousands place.  We can check if $N$ has $592$ in the ten thousands place by taking $\left\lfloor \frac N{10^4}\right\rfloor \bmod 1000$ and asking if it is $592$  The division and floor strip off the lower four digits and the $\bmod 1000$ strips off the higher digits.

To generalize this note that $n$ has $\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor +1=k$ digits and $N$ has $\lfloor \log_{10}N\rfloor +1=K$ digits, so the ones digit of $n$ cannot be any higher than the $10^{K-k}$ digit of $N$ and still fit.  We loop over $i=0$ to $K-k$ and ask if $\left\lfloor \frac N{10^i}\right\rfloor \bmod 10^{k-1}=n$.  If we find one, then $n$ is a substring of $N$